# Adding recursive copy method to linked list implementation in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list

Hi I implemented a linked list in Python and I got this piece of code that can copy the linked list to another linked list **but I cannot understand why its inserting at 0 index instead?**

Then wouldn't the copied list be reversed? But I tried running it and the output is correct and is in order?

My insert function

```
def insert(self, index, item):
    if index<0 and index<-1*len(self):
        raise IndexError("Negative index out of range")
    elif index>0 and index>=len(self):
        raise IndexError("Positive index out of range")

    if index==0:
        self.head=Node(item,self.head)

    elif index>0:
        node=self._get_node(index-1)
        node.next=Node(item,node.next)

    else:
        node=self._get_node(index+len(self))
        node.next=Node(item,node.next)
    self.count+=1
```

My copy function

```
 def copy(self):
    new_list=linkedList()
    self._copy_aux_(self.head,new_list)
    return new_list

 def _copy_aux_(self, node, new_list):
    if node is not None:
        self._copy_aux_(node.next, new_list)
        new_list.insert(0,node.item)
```

Can someone please help explain this?Any help will be appreciated thanks!

EDIT:Okay apparently it inserts the last item first?Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 -When you call insert with index equal to zero you insert the list item upfront, that is, in the location pointed by head(see method def insert(self, index, item):
2 - When the method copy is called the method def _copy_aux_(self, node, new_list): is called recursively until the last item of the list is reached, which has node.next equals to None. 
3 - After that, after each return  from the method _copy_aux_, it starts inserting the itens in the new_list up front from the last to the first item, which gives the correct order.

I suggest to include prints  to trace the list copy recursion, as the code below:

```
def copy(self):
        print('Trace copy:')
        new_list=linkedList()
        self._copy_aux_(self.head,new_list)
        return new_list

    def _copy_aux(self, node, new_list):
        if node is not None:
            self._copy_aux_(node.next, new_list)
            new_list.insert(0,node.item)
            print(new_list)
```

then run the following example (taken from https://repl.it/@MuhammadFermi/week8-2):

```
list = linkedList()
list.insert(0, 3)
list.insert(0, 9)
list.insert(0, 2)
list.insert(0, 5)
list.insert(0, 1)
list.insert(2, 6)
list.insert(10, 7)
print(list)
print(len(list))
print(3 in list)
list2 = list.copy()
print('list2 =')
print(list2)
```

You should get the following results:

```
1, 5, 6, 2, 9, 3, 7, 
7
True
Trace copy:
7, 
3, 7, 
9, 3, 7, 
2, 9, 3, 7, 
6, 2, 9, 3, 7, 
5, 6, 2, 9, 3, 7, 
1, 5, 6, 2, 9, 3, 7, 
list2 =
1, 5, 6, 2, 9, 3, 7, 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest flattening your list, and then re-inserting the values into a new list:

```
class LinkedList:
   def __init__(self, value = None):
     self.head = value
     self._next = None
   def insert_node(self, _val):
     if self.head is None:
       self.head = _val   
     else:
       getattr(self._next, 'insert_node', lambda x:setattr(self, '_next', LinkedList(x)))(_val)
   def flatten(self):
     return [self.head, *getattr(self._next, 'flatten', lambda :[])()]
   @classmethod
   def copy(cls, l):
      t = cls()
      for i in l.flatten():
        t.insert_node(i)
      return t

l = LinkedList()
for i in range(10):
  l.insert_node(i)
new_l = LinkedList.copy(l)
```